# unable to match edittext with image name

Tags: java, android

Learning android by making a simple guessing game, I have set the images in an Arraylist and applied random operation on it, but now I'm confused how to match edit text value with image name so that I can set score.

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText editText;
    private Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ImageView random_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        final int[] images = {R.drawable.kung_fu_panda, R.drawable.mr_nobody, R.drawable.toy_story};
        list.add(R.drawable.kung_fu_panda);
        list.add(R.drawable.mr_nobody);
        list.add(R.drawable.toy_story);
        int position = new Random().nextInt(list.size());
        random_image.setImageResource((Integer) list.get(position));
        list.remove(position);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                validateInput();
            }
        });

    }

    private void validateInput() {
        String input = editText.getText().toString();

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try definition name's array of images, and get the name by random position, and use `currentName` save the name.

```
String currentName;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ImageView random_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    final String imageNames = {"kung fu panda", "mr nobody", "toy story"};
    list.add(R.drawable.kung_fu_panda);
    list.add(R.drawable.mr_nobody);
    list.add(R.drawable.toy_story);
    int position = new Random().nextInt(list.size());
    random_image.setImageResource((Integer) list.get(position));
    currentName = imageNames[position];
    list.remove(position);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            validateInput();
        }
    });

}
```

Then, in your `validateInput()` method, you can use `currentName` to compare, notice case, use `String.toLowerCase()` to format input string.

```
private boolean validateInput() {
    String input = editText.getText().toString();
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(input)){
         input = input..toLowerCase();
         if(input.equeals(currentName)){
             return true;
         }
    }
    return false;
}
```